# C: Segmentation fault 11 only in terminal, not in debugger

Tags: c, debugging, terminal, lldb

I'm making a program which reads a file, reverses it bit by bit and stores the result in a new file without allocating chunks larger than 1kb. When i run it in the terminal, it creates the file but doesn't write in it, instead it crashes and gives segmentation fault 11. When i try to debug it using lldb the entire code runs without any problems. Does my terminal follow different allocation rules than lldb? How can i solve this?

I've ran the code with large and small files but even with a nearly empty txt file it crashes. 
I am running osx 10.10.5 with lldb-340.4.119

```
int const CHUNK_SIZE = 1024;
int chunk_index = 0;
int character;
char new_filename[] = "output";

struct Chunk {
  struct Chunk *previous;
  int data[(CHUNK_SIZE-sizeof(struct Chunk*))/sizeof(int)];
};

struct Chunk* memory = (struct Chunk *)malloc(sizeof(struct Chunk));
struct Chunk* temp;

FILE *fp;
fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");

    // read file into memory
character = fgetc(fp);
do {
  memory->data[chunk_index] = character;
  chunk_index++;
  if ( chunk_index*sizeof(int) > CHUNK_SIZE-sizeof(struct Chunk*)){
    chunk_index = 0;
    temp = (struct Chunk *)malloc(sizeof(struct Chunk));
    temp->previous = memory;
    memory = temp;
  }
  character = fgetc(fp);
}
while (character !=EOF);
chunk_index--;
fclose(fp);


    // write to new file
fp = fopen(new_filename, "wb");

do {
  while (chunk_index >=0) {
    printf("%c", memory->data[chunk_index]);
    fprintf(fp, "%c", memory->data[chunk_index]);
    chunk_index--;
  }

  chunk_index = (CHUNK_SIZE-sizeof(struct Chunk*))/sizeof(int);
  temp = memory;
  memory = memory->previous;
  free(temp);
} while(memory!=NULL);
```

Comment: `chunk_index*sizeof(int) > CHUNK_SIZE-sizeof(struct Chunk*)` I think that should be `chunk_index*sizeof(int) >= CHUNK_SIZE-sizeof(struct Chunk*)`.

Comment: `while(memory!=NULL)` - why would it be `NULL` ever? You never set it.

Comment: Please consider posting a [mcve].

Comment: `CHUNK_SIZE-sizeof(struct Chunk*)` relies on assumptions: `sizeof(struct Chunk*) ` is a multiple of `sizeof(int)` (Likely but not certain) and `struct Chunk` has no padding again likely but not certain.

Comment: `memory->data[chunk_index] = character;` can put `EOF` into `memory->data[0]`.  Recommend `while` at the top of the loop.

Comment: @EugeneSh. because i keep changing memory to memory->previous untill i'm back at the first memory block i've created. If memory == null then i must've just had the last block.

Comment: Have you ever set it to `NULL`? I don't see it in the code. `malloc` is not initializing memory. Anyway [mcve] is needed.

Comment: Build with `-g`, enable core dumps, run it, it will write core file, open core file in gdb, look at callstack.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The difference between running in a debugger and without it may be due to the debugger disabling ASLR. This may hide the problem when you're trying to debug it.

Try undoing this. It [seems](http://lists.llvm.org/pipermail/lldb-dev/2014-August/004867.html) that in LLDB it should be done with the command

```
settings set target.disable-aslr false
```

which should undo the disabling of ASLR. In GDB it would be

```
set disable-randomization off
```

Don't forget to restart the program under your debugger (without restarting the debugger!) to make this setting take effect. In GDB it's the `run` command, something similar should be in LLDB.